# Combining files from a list based on date

Tags: r, date

I have a list of files that are all named similarly: "FlightTrackDATE.txt" where the date is expressed in YYYYMMDD.  I read in all the files with the list.files() command, but this gives me all the files in that folder (only flight track files are in this folder).  What I would like to do is create a new file that will combine all the files from the last 90 days (or three months, whichever is easier) and ignore the other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    #date from which you want to consolidate (replace with required date)
    fromDate = as.Date("2015-12-23")


    for (filename in list.files()){

      #extract the date from filename using substr ( characters 12- 19)
      filenameDate = as.Date(substr(filename,12,19), format = "%Y%m%d")

      #read and consolidate if the filedate is on or after from date 
      if ((filenameDate - fromDate) >=0){

          #create consolidated list from first file 
          if (!exists('consolidated')){
            consolidated <- read.table(filename, header = TRUE)
          } else{

            data = read.table(filename, header = TRUE)
            #row bind to consolidate
            consolidated = rbind(consolidated, data)
          }

      }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

I have three sample files :

```
FlightTrack20151224.txt
FlightTrack20151223.txt
FlightTrack20151222.txt
```

Sample data:

```
Name    Speed
AA101   23
```

Consolidated data:

```
  Name  Speed
1 AA102 24
2 AA101 23
```

**Note:**

*1. Create the From date by subtracting from current date or using a fixed date like above.*

*2. Remember to clean up the existing consolidated data if you are running the script again. Data duplication might occur otherwise.*

*3. Save consolidated to file :)*

Answer (score 0):

Consider an `lapply()` solution without a need for `list.files()` since you know ahead of time the directory and file name structure:

```
path = "C:/path/to/txt/files"

# LIST OF ALL LAST 90 DATES IN YYYYMMDD FORMAT
dates <- lapply(0:90, function(x) format(Sys.Date()-x, "%Y%m%d"))

# IMPORT ALL FILES INTO A LIST OF DATAFRAMES
dfList <- lapply(paste0(path, "FlightTrack", dates, ".txt"),                  
                 function(x) if (file.exists(x)) {read.table(x)})

# COMBINE EACH DATA FRAME INTO ONE
df <- do.call(rbind, dfList)

# OUTPUT FINAL FILE TO TXT
write.table(df, paste0(path, "FlightTrack90Days.txt"), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```